# number of customers per number of invoices

Tags: sql-server, analytics

I have a table containing
customerID, InvoiceID,  ProductID,  Date,   Income,
I need to count the number of clients by the number of invoices

I need to write a query that returns something like

Invoice amount ------ number of client that have that amount of invoices

1  ------------------------   4

2  ------------------------   3

4  ------------------------   7

Here's what I've tried

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customerID) AS 'Number of Clients', 
       COUNT(InvoiceID) AS 'Number of Invoices' 
FROM Sheet 
GROUP BY COUNT(InvoiceID) 
ORDER BY COUNT(InvoiceID)
```

but I can't use aggregate field in group by

Comment: And what have you tried?  Hint: first group by customerId.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customerID) AS 'Number of Clients', COUNT(InvoiceID) AS 'Number of Invoices'
FROM Sheet
GROUP BY COUNT(InvoiceID)
ORDER BY COUNT(InvoiceID)

I can't use aggregate field in group by

Answer (score 0):

You need a nested select to first calculate the number of invoices per customer. The outer select can then calculate the number of customers for each invoice count.

```
SELECT [Number of Invoices], COUNT(*) AS [Number of Clients]
FROM (
    SELECT customerID, COUNT(DISTINCT InvoiceID) AS [Number of Invoices]
    FROM Sheet
    GROUP BY customerID
) A
GROUP BY [Number of Invoices]
ORDER BY [Number of Invoices]
```

A common table expression can also be used in place of the nested select:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT customerID, COUNT(DISTINCT InvoiceID) AS [Number of Invoices]
    FROM Sheet
    GROUP BY customerID
)
SELECT [Number of Invoices], COUNT(*) AS [Number of Clients]
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [Number of Invoices]
ORDER BY [Number of Invoices]
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OVR1TrGz) for a demo or [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hp942ekM) that contains your originally posted data (but a different result).

*(The above has been updated to include `DISTINCT` to `COUNT(DISTINCT InvoiceID)` to handle multiple rows with the same customerID and InvoiceID in the originally posted data.)*